# VLAN, possible to do this?

Tags: networking, router, vlan

I have a Cisco RV110W small buisiness router.
Here is a demo of what the administration interface/options:
https://www.cisco.com/web/sbtg/gui_mockups/RV110W/default.asp.htm

I have 3 devices connected on Port #1. All 3 devics connect to a unmanaged switch and the switch connects to the Port #1 of the router.

Is it possible to put 2 machines in VLAN 1 and the other machine in VLAN2 WITHOUT changing the physical cable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only if the devices support sending their own vlan tags on the traffic (and assuming that the unmanaged switch will pass the vlan tags unmolested, which most unmanaged switches will), with the Cisco configured for port 1 to be a trunk port so that it will listen to the tags.

This is a pretty hacky solution - it would be much better to have the switch that these devices uplink to be vlan aware.

Comment: Beat me to it, but yes, a managed switch would be the best solution.